# UIBarButtonItems invisible issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar added to the view in interface builder. And I need to add some buttons to it programmatically. So what I do is calling this method inside the viewDidLoad method. The items are added as the action method is executed but they are not visible.

```
- (void) addingNumberOfLettersBar {
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image1 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(changeNumberOfLettersToShow:)];
//UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:@selector(changeNumberOfLettersToShow:)];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];
barButtonItem1.tag = 1;

UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image3 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(changeNumberOfLettersToShow:)];
barButtonItem3.tag = 3;

UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4"];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image4 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(changeNumberOfLettersToShow:)];
barButtonItem4.tag = 4;

UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5"];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem5 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image5 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(changeNumberOfLettersToShow:)];
barButtonItem5.tag = 5;

UIImage *image5p = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5+"];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem5p = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image5p style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(changeNumberOfLettersToShow:)];
barButtonItem5p.tag = 0;

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButtonItem1, flexibleItem, barButtonItem3, flexibleItem, barButtonItem4, flexibleItem, barButtonItem5, flexibleItem, barButtonItem5p, nil];


self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;  
}
```

Comment: check your image contains some extenson or not ,for example **[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];**

Comment: no everything is ok with the images. they are added to assets so I don't need to add extension

Comment: check ur image size is not grater than 20 x 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your image size. It should not be much large. Set tint color to every button and check is it visible or not.

and you should create `barbuttonitem` in your case like,

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)];
```

Comment: hmm setting the tint colour works - I can see a coloured round. but I tried to add a system button as I thought that the problem occurred due to the image size and I didn't see it as well

Comment: If you think it is helpful then accept answer so other people with similar issue can use it :)

Comment: the button is still not visible(( I just have rounds with tint color

Comment: That means there is a problem in image size i think because if you see round that means button is added properly.